# Saving a mail message in applescript

Tags: email, checkbox, applescript

I'm new to applescript and I'm having enormous trouble doing something which seems very basic.  I'm trying to save a selected mail message in RTF format with attachments.  Here is the errant script:

```
    tell application "Mail"
        activate
        set AllMessages to selection
        set myMessage to item 1 of AllMessages
        open myMessage
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Mail"
                tell menu bar 1
                    tell menu bar item "File"
                        tell menu "File"
                            click menu item "Save As…"
                            delay 2
                            keystroke "test"
                            click checkbox "Include Attachments" -- result: ERROR
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
set the clipboard to POSIX path of (path to desktop as text) & "test"

tell application "Mail"
    open first item of (get selection)
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Mail"
        click menu item "Save As…" of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
        delay 3
        perform action "AXPress" of pop up button 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
        click menu item 1 of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
        if value of checkbox "Include Attachments" of group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1 = 0 then
            perform action "AXPress" of checkbox "Include Attachments" of group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
        end if
        keystroke "g" using {command down, shift down}
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
        keystroke return
        keystroke return

    end tell
end tell
```